# Symbol for the length of a line/vector?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How do I make a symbol for the length of a line or vector?
I intend the following notation: |AD| is the length of AD. I can't find this symbol anywhere. (When I use `shift+backslash` in LaTeX, it gives a horizontal line).

For some reason the `\cdot` also doesn't seem to work, when I write it down like this:

```
&|AD| \cdot |BD|& = ...
```

So can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try putting them in math mode `$\| AB \|$` and `&` is a special character (in geeneral) column separator for tables and arrays.

Comment: Have a look at this question and its answers [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet).

Comment: `shift+\ ` to me means `|` (a vertical bar). Do you get an horizontal line?

Comment: @LudovicC.  The question was not about any symbol, but about delimiters instead.  In that sense it is *not* a duplicate of the cited answer.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Sure but it turns out that Detexify provides the right commands to get this delimiter. Plus I don't see really the difference between a symbol and a delimiter (in this context).

Comment: @LudovicC. The same “symbol”, e.g., |, may serve different purposes.

Answer (score 7):

Usually you use `\[ \lvert AD \rvert \cdot \lvert BD \rvert \]` relying on the `amsmath` package for this task. Often people wrap this into a macro called `\abs` or `\norm` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
    \norm{AD}\cdot\norm{BD}
\]
\[
    \lvert AD \rvert \cdot \lvert BD \rvert
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `|`, as you wish, but in the math mode: $|AD|\cdot|CD|$. The same character from a keyboard gives in text mode horizontal line (em dash, in fact).

Comment: Ow!! I've just discovered that the vertical bar in text mode produces an em dash line... lol